# SQL Server linked-server - cannot see all of the rows in target server's database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I can't see all of the rows in the linked-server's tables. So if I run select count(*) from cmrez.dbo.reservations on the target server itself it returns 809472, but if I run the same query from a remote (linked) server I only get 78324. What's up with that!?

Comment: OK - it turns out that the source server also has a database/table called CMREZ.dbo.reservations, so that is what is being queried. So the linked server isn't linking correctly.

Comment: You're using the fully qualified object name, right?  ie `SELECT * FROM <linkedServer>.<database>.<schema>.<table>`

Comment: Yes - I am using the fully qualified object name.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have come up with a solution. The target server supports mixed-mode logins, so I created a new login and I specify for the linked server to use that login and it appears to work. I don't know why I couldn't use pass-through security, but that doesn't matter as long as it works ;-).